# pdfbox 2.0.16 , setCanFillInForm not working

Tags: java, pdfbox

I prepared a template with form fields. Using my java code i fill the template with data as needed and save as another pdf.
I dont want form fields to be edited after my program fills the data.
I tried following code and it is not working:

```
    AccessPermission ap = new AccessPermission();
    ap.setCanModify(false);
    ap.setCanFillInForm(false);
    ap.setReadOnly();
    StandardProtectionPolicy spp = new StandardProtectionPolicy("owner-password", "", ap);
    spp.setEncryptionKeyLength(128);
    pDDocument.protect(spp);
```

Also, directly setting accesspermission:

```
pDDocument.getCurrentAccessPermission().setCanFillInForm(false);
pDDocument.getCurrentAccessPermission().setCanModify(false);
pDDocument.getCurrentAccessPermission().setReadOnly();
```

Both options didnt work. I am able to edit the form field. Can someone please help

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr can you please help here

Comment: Please share the result PDF. With "able to edit", do you mean with Adobe Reader or programatically?

Comment: Thanks @TilmanHausherr for your response. I was filling pdf programtically using pdfbox 2.0.16 version. but i fixed the issue. readonly worked when i set at individual field level: